# Is it possible to modify the value of one array while searching through another in Javascript and Vue?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, checkbox, vue.js

If I have two arrays that both contain objects. Is it possible to modify the item value of one array while looping through another if certain items match? Such as a name?

Currently, I'm looping though the first array, displaying the names, with checkboxes (all checked) beside them.  *If I **uncheck** the checkbox, set both arrays where the name is the same, to `visible: false`*

I'm also using Vue, if that makes things any easier

Say;

```
array 1 = [{Name: John, Age: 19, Visible: false}, {Name: Frank, Age: 20, Visible: true}, {Name: Kate, Age: 20, Visible: true}]

array 2 = [{Name: John, Age: 30, Visible: true}, {Name: William, Age: 20, Visible: true}, {Name: Henry, Age: 40, Visible: true}]
```

Is it possible to set it where ***if two names match, set both to visible false***. In this example, it would be "John".  So "John" in the first array is `visible: true`, so I'd like both to be `visible: false`

Comment: could you share a tried example or your template

Comment: Sure.  It's quite large, populating charts etc. I'll need some time to simplify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If efficiency is not your priority, you can just use a nested loop and set Visible to false whenever the Name is found in both arrays:

```js
var array1 = [{Name: 'John', Age: 19, Visible: false}, {Name: 'Frank', Age: 20, Visible: true}, {Name: 'Kate', Age: 20, Visible: true}]
var array2 = [{Name: 'John', Age: 30, Visible: true}, {Name: 'William', Age: 20, Visible: true}, {Name: 'Henry', Age: 40, Visible: true}]

array1.forEach(obj1 => {
  array2.forEach(obj2 => {
    if (obj1.Name === obj2.Name) {
      obj1.Visible = false
      obj2.Visible = false
    }
  })
})

console.log(array1, array2)
```

Comment: A great answer.  Nice and simple, and yes, for my current work, this would work well. Thank you! Just out of curiosity, how would it work if there were three arrays?

Comment: The naive way is to embed another nested loop `array1.forEach(obj1 => {
  array2.forEach(obj2 => {
    array3.forEach(obj3 => {
    if (obj1.Name === obj2.Name && obj1.Name === obj3.Name) {
      obj1.Visible = false;
      obj2.Visible = false;
      obj3.Visible = false;
    }
   })
  })
})`

Answer (score 2):

If there are only two arrays, I think you can do this with a loop and if condition (and ideally, you'd [break out](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_break.asp) of the function).  If you have more than one object that could be a match for the name, don't use the break, otherwise, it is more efficient so you won't be looping through values that you know won't match.  The code should look something like this:

```
function someUnCheckFunction(uncheckedNameValue) {
    arrayOne.forEach(function(item, index) {
        if(item.Name == uncheckedNameValue) {
            item.Visible = false;
            break;  // this will stop the loop.  If you have multiple objects with the same Name, remove it
        }
    });
    arrayTwo.forEach(function(item, index) {
        if(item.Name == uncheckedNameValue) {
            item.Visible = false;
            break;  // this will stop the loop.  If you have multiple objects with the same Name, remove it
        }
    });
}

function someCheckFunction(checkedNameValue) {
    arrayOne.forEach(function(item, index) {
        if(item.Name == uncheckedNameValue) {
            item.Visible = true;
            break;  // this will stop the loop.  If you have multiple objects with the same Name, remove it
        }
    });
    arrayTwo.forEach(function(item, index) {
        if(item.Name == uncheckedNameValue) {
            item.Visible = true;
            break;  // this will stop the loop.  If you have multiple objects with the same Name, remove it
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!